# ListPlot - plotting values with different range

Tags: plotting, graphics, version-7, overlay

I have three tables: `L, S` and `U`. In first table I have values from range `(0,1)`, in second from `(0,2*10^27)` and in the third one from `(0,50)`. No I want to plot all this three tables (tables have the same domain) together. But because of a very different range, I see for example only values for `U`, and rest are just like a small points very near to axes x. I was trying to use `ImageCompose`, because I have mathematica 7, so I can't use `Overlay`, but this functions are only for two plots. 
Is any other solution how can I plot this three functions together and make the plot more legible?

Comment: How about plotting `{L, S/(2 10^27), U/50}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is all about rescaling, - visual with `Overlay` or @A.G. idea in the comment. So:

```
L = Abs[Rescale[Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, 1000]]]];
S = 2 10^27 Abs[Rescale[Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, 1000]]]];
U = 50 Abs[Rescale[Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, 1000]]]];

ListPlot[Rescale /@ {L, S, U}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I just don't understand, why you made: S = 50 Abs[Rescale[Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, 1000]]]];, because S is from (0;2*10^27)

Comment: @Ziva A typo, corrected.